# Data.Sequence.Seq lazy parallel Functor instance

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, lazy-evaluation, finger-tree

I need parallel (but lazy) version of `fmap` for [`Seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html#t:Seq) from [`Data.Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html) package. But package doesn't export any `Seq` data constructors. So I can't just wrap it in `newtype` and implement `Functor` directly for the `newtype`.

Can I do it without rewriting the whole package?

Comment: What do you mean by "parallel (but lazy)"? Those seem like a contradiction in terms to me. In any case my suggestion would be to apply the usual `fmap` for `Seq`, and then do whatever parallel evaluation you want on the result.

Comment: I mean lazy for this case: `or $ odd \`pfmap\` (fromList [4, 3, undefined]) -- => True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is probably to `splitAt` the sequence into chunks, `fmap` over each chunk, and then append the pieces back together. `Seq` is represented as a [finger tree](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.html), so its underlying structure isn't particularly well suited to parallel algorithms—if you split it up by its natural structure, successive threads will get larger and larger pieces. If you want to give it a go, you can copy the definition of the `FingerTree` type from the `Data.Sequence` source, and use `unsafeCoerce` to convert between it and a `Seq`. You'll probably want to send the first few `Deep` nodes to one thread, but then you'll have to think pretty carefully about the rest. Finger trees can be very far from weight-balanced, primarily because `3^n` grows asymptotically faster than `2^n`; you'll need to take that into account to balance work among threads.

There are at least two sensible ways to split up the sequence, assuming you use `splitAt`:

1. Split it all before breaking the computation into threads. If you do this, you should split it from left to right or right to left, because splitting off small pieces is cheaper than splitting off large ones and then splitting those. You should append the results in a similar fashion.
2. Split it recursively in multiple threads. This might make sense if you want a lot of pieces or more potential laziness. Split the list near the middle and send each piece to a thread for further splitting and processing.

There's another splitting approach that might be nicer, using the machinery currently used to implement `zipWith` (see the GitHub ticket I filed requesting `chunksOf`), but I don't know that you'd get a huge benefit in this application.

The non-strict behavior you seek seems unlikely to work in general. You can probably make it work in many or most specific cases, but I'm not too optimistic that you'll find a totally general approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it's actually not so efficient.

```
-- | A combination of 'parTraversable' and 'fmap', encapsulating a common pattern:
--
-- > parFmap strat f = withStrategy (parTraversable strat) . fmap f
--
parFmap         :: Traversable t => Strategy b -> (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
parFmap strat f = (`using` parTraversable strat) . fmap f

-- | Parallel version of '<$>'
(<$|>) :: Traversable t =>  (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
(<$|>) = parFmap rpar
```